Design a simple load circuit for a LDO
I want to draw 3A from this LDO "LT3083EDFTRPBF":

I plan to verify the thermal performance of the LDO when I draw 3A and do some measurement, would you pleases let me know what is the simplest way that I can draw 3A from the circuit? what sort of load do you suggest?

The simplest way would be to use a power resistor rated for at least 15W with a resistance close to 1.6Ω.
There is one from Vishay RH0501R600FC02 that can handle 50W.
Or if you want to do more advanced testing or plan on doing similar tests in the future it might be worth it to invest in an adjustable load which you can get from Aliexpress starting at just 30€.
If you don't want either of those but have a bunch of small resistors laying around you could solder a bunch of the in parallel until you have enough to handle the 15W but you need to use a pretty high value as the resistance goes down the more you add in parallel.

thanks for your useful answer, would you please also vote on my question? thanks

Beyond the Ohm's Law calculation, pay attention to the power dissipation.
If a resistor rated for 15 W dissipation is in fact dissipating the full 15 W, it will get so hot that it can scorch whatever is below it, or desolder itself from a pc board.
A better way is to use three 5 ohm resistors in parallel.  Because this is a common value, they will be lower cost and much easier to buy.
A common rule-of-thumb for long-term reliability is to limit the power dissipation to no more than 50% of a component's rating.  For a lower case temperature and much better reliability, I would use resistors rated for at least 10 W each; 20 W would be better.  Be sure to leave an air gap between the parts.
An alternative is to use multiple 10 ohm resistors in parallel.  Each added resistor increases the regulator output current by 0.5 A.

thank you very much for the useful formation, I appreciate your help.

The simplest way? Get a resistor that will draw 3 A at the rated output voltage and with a high enough wattage rating.
$$
R = \frac{E}{I} = \frac{5 V}{3 A} = 1.666... \Omega
$$
$$
W = E\times I = 5 V \times 3 A = 15 W
$$
So 1.666 Ω and probably 20 W or more to give a safety margin should do it.

thank you very much for the useful formation, I appreciate your help.
